# Python interpreter to show error

Tags: python, logging, interpreter

I am running my code locally on `XAMPP` at the moment.

I currently have my `log` file setup as follows:

**log.py**

```
import logging

def setup_custom_logger(name):
formatter = logging.Formatter(fmt='%(asctime)s - %(levelname)s - %(module)s - %(message)s')

handler = logging.FileHandler('error.log')
handler.setFormatter(formatter)

logger = logging.getLogger(name)
logger = logging.getLogger('sqlalchemy.engine')
logger.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)
logger.addHandler(handler)
return logger
```

Here is an example of what I mean:
**views.py**

```
import log
logger = log.setup_custom_logger('root')
@app.route('/restaurants', methods = ['GET'])
def getRestaurants():

    try:       
        restaurantsList = session.query(Restaurant).all() 
    except:
        logger.debug("couldnt get restaurants")
```

**sqltables.py**

```
class Restaurant(Base):
__tablename__ = 'restaurant'

RESTAURANTID = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
RESTAURANTNAME = Column(String(50), nullable=False)
RESTAURANTDESCRIPTION = Column(String(1024))
RESTAURANTCUISINE = Column(String(1024))
RESTAURANTOPENING = Column(String(512))
RESTAURANTEMAIL = Column(String(100))
RESTAURANTPHONE = Column(String(100))
RESTAURANTADDRESS = Column(String(100))

waiter = relationship(u'Waiter', secondary='restaurant_waiter')
user = relationship(u'User', secondary='restaurant_users')

def serialize(self): 
    return {           
    'id': self.RESTAURANTID, 
    'name': self.RESTAURANTNAME,
    'description': self.RESTAURANTDESCRIPTION,
    'cuisine': self.RESTAURANTCUISINE,
    'opening': self.RESTAURANTOPENING,
    'email': self.RESTAURANTEMAIL,
    'phone': self.RESTAURANTPHONE,
    'address': self.RESTAURANTADDRESS
    }
```

In the above instance, I receive a `500` error message in the browser.

I get this in `error.log`

```
2015-03-13 19:11:07,924 - INFO - base - SHOW VARIABLES LIKE 'sql_mode'
2015-03-13 19:11:07,924 - INFO - base - ()
2015-03-13 19:11:07,924 - DEBUG - result - Col ('Variable_name', 'Value')
2015-03-13 19:11:07,924 - DEBUG - result - Row ('sql_mode', 'NO_ENGINE_SUBSTITUTION')
2015-03-13 19:11:07,924 - INFO - base - SELECT DATABASE()
2015-03-13 19:11:07,924 - INFO - base - ()
2015-03-13 19:11:07,924 - DEBUG - result - Col ('DATABASE()',)
2015-03-13 19:11:07,924 - DEBUG - result - Row ('lokachat_menumaster',)
2015-03-13 19:11:07,924 - INFO - base - show collation where `Charset` = 'utf8' and `Collation` = 'utf8_bin'
2015-03-13 19:11:07,924 - INFO - base - ()
2015-03-13 19:11:07,924 - DEBUG - result - Col ('Collation', 'Charset', 'Id', 'Default', 'Compiled', 'Sortlen')
2015-03-13 19:11:07,924 - DEBUG - result - Row ('utf8_bin', 'utf8', 83L, '', 'Yes', 1L)
2015-03-13 19:11:07,924 - INFO - base - SELECT CAST('test plain returns' AS CHAR(60)) AS anon_1
2015-03-13 19:11:07,924 - INFO - base - ()
2015-03-13 19:11:07,924 - INFO - base - SELECT CAST('test unicode returns' AS CHAR(60)) AS anon_1
2015-03-13 19:11:07,924 - INFO - base - ()
2015-03-13 19:11:07,924 - INFO - base - SELECT CAST('test collated returns' AS CHAR CHARACTER SET utf8) COLLATE utf8_bin AS anon_1
2015-03-13 19:11:07,924 - INFO - base - ()
2015-03-13 19:11:07,924 - DEBUG - views - couldnt get restaurants
```

The `Apache Error log` doesn't contain anything helpful either.

How can I get more information to print in my log file?

Comment: You got something mixed up I think: XAMPP runs PHP applications with Apache, not Python apps. Or maybe you have set up something more advanced?

Comment: Hey @mavroprovato, Python can be set up with it too :)

Comment: Check if error.log created in same path as log.py

Comment: Yeah I know. So please add more information about your configuration

Answer (score 0):

OP use of `logging` is incorrect.

I suggest to always follow this pattern:

```
logging.debug("user %r", user)
```

This will handle odd values like `None` or `3.1459` correctly, and also convert unprintable strings correctly.

Finally, since it's a web server, may I recommend that you wrap top-level functions in a `try/except` block, e.g.:

```
try:
    render_user_or_something()
except:
    logging.exception("oh no!")
    raise
```

While that doesn't solve your problem in itself, it will show you where your code broke.

Comment: Thanks for that @qarma. Didn't know about the `%r`. Will give it a shot.